# Custom Action to set INSTALLFOLDER path

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

So I created this customAction that gets me the path of another app using Registries

```
string value = Registry.GetValue(userRoot, key, -1).ToString();
session["INSTALLLOCATION"] = value;
```

And it works. The problem is how I send it back to the .wxs file and set the installation path of something to be that string value. I have this thing in the Wix file:

```
    <CustomAction Id="CustomAction" Property="CustomAction2" Value="path=[INSTALLLOCATION]" />
    
    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.ProAdmin_TargetDir)ExtractRegistryPath\bin\Debug\ExtractRegistryPath.CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="CustomAction2" Impersonate="no" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Return="check" Execute="deferred"/>

<InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomAction" Before="CustomAction2" />
      <Custom Action='CustomAction2' Before="ExecuteAction" />
    </InstallUISequence>
```

This thing throws an 2762 error code.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting error 2762 because you can't have deferred actions in the InstallUISequence. The custom action that populates the INSTALLLOCATION property should be called at the beginning of both the InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence as an 'immediate' action - and - INSTALLLOCATION should be a folder in the Directory table.